# Python: create a list of lists

Tags: python

I have two list

```
l1= ["apple", "orange"]
l2 = ["red", green", "black", "blue"]
```

I want to create a list which appends both.

```
l3 = [["apple", "orange"], ["red", green", "black", "blue"]].
```

So the `l3[0] =["apple", "orange"]` and `l3[1]=["red", green", "black", "blue"]`.

How do I do the above?

Answer (score 2):

Just put the references in.

```
l3 = [l1, l2]
```

Note that, if you do this, modifying `l1` or `l2` will also produce the same changes in `l3`. If you don't want this to happen, use a copy:

```
l3 = [l1[:], l2[:]]
```

This will work for shallow lists. If they are nested, you're better off using `deepcopy`:

```
import copy
l3 = [copy.deepcopy(l1), copy.deepcopy(l2)]
```

Comment: If the downvoter or someone else would care to explain what is wrong with this answer, I would love to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

Just do the following:

```
l3 = [l1, l2]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Either**:

```
>>> l1= ["apple", "orange"] 
>>> l2 =["red", "green", "black", "blue"]
>>> l3 = list()
>>> l3.append(l1)
>>> l3.append(l2)
>>> l3
[['apple', 'orange'], ['red', 'green', 'black', 'blue']]
```

use append() to append a list to your list 3

**Or**:

```
l3 = [l1, l2]
```

No matter which way you choose, the result:

```
>>> l3[0]
['apple', 'orange']
>>> l3[1]
['red', 'green', 'black', 'blue']
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `.append()` method.

First, create a new array, then append the first list, then the second:

```
l3 = []
l3.append(l1)
l3.append(l2)
```

This gives you:

```
l3 = [["apple", "orange"], ["red", green", "black", "blue"]]
```

You can also do this shorter method:

```
l3 = [l1, l2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6]
```

You can do:

```
l3 = list()
l3.append(l1)
l3.append(l2)
```

or:

```
l3 = [l1,l2]
```